# Keyboard pushes up my webview framework7 cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

in my app, I have a lot of page where there are form. All in this page, when an input has focus, the keyboard pushes up my webview and the upper part of the page, navbar and side panel is not visible anymore.

I want to prevent the keyboard pushing up the webview. I read another question about this problem on the forum but neither help me to solve the issue. I installed the plugin
https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard with the command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-keyboard
```

in my cordova project. How can I solve it? Thank you in advance

I put this code into index.js

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

 Keyboard.shrinkView(true);
 Keyboard.disableScrollingInShrinkView(true);
 Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(true);}
```

I also try to put in my-app,js but nothing change.
I also try to change

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

with

```
 "adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Android version: android 7.1.1
Cordova version: cordova 8.1.2

Comment: You need to give more information: What platform are you encountering the issue on (Android or iOS)? What OS version (e.g. iOS 12.1)? What plugins are in your project? (e.g. `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`)

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Android version: android 7.1.1
Cordova version: cordova 8.1.2 and Plugin:  cordova-plugin-keyboard

Comment: Same on IOS Cordova with Framework7 4.4.3